# webpack + babel loader source map references empty file

Tags: webpack, babeljs, source-maps

I have an es6 project which I bundle using webpack + babel loader.
When I open the devtools I can see 'webpack://' and all my sources (es6) underneath.

The problems are: breakpoints don't hit and function references directs me to a file name '?d41d

which has the following content:

```
undefined


/** WEBPACK FOOTER **
 ** 
 **/
```

if I drill down from document script to a function in my bundle I get to the ?d41d file as well

my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {

    debug: true,
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: "entry.js",
    output: {
        path: "C:/html5/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015'],
                    plugins: ['transform-object-assign'],
                    sourceMaps: ['inline']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

and part of package.json in case it might help:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^0.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "cheerio": "^0.22.0",
    "chokidar-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "eslint": "^3.3.1",
    "html-to-js": "0.0.1",
    "jsdoc": "^3.4.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.4.2",
    "minami": "^1.1.1",
    "obfuscator": "^0.5.4",
    "sinon": "^1.17.5",
    "uglify-js": "^2.7.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "yargs": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel introduced a different sourcemap format [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3658) and Webpack didn't handle it correctly.
The fix was merged in [this PR](https://github.com/webpack/source-list-map/pull/2), and **released in Webpack 1.14.0**.

Answer (score 8):

This also just started happening to me today,

I'm not sure what the root of the problem is, but switching `devtool` from `cheap-module-eval-source-map` to `sourceMap` has fixed the problem for the time being.

Comment: I used all the possible devtools options mentioned on webpack's site. all resulted with the same output

Comment: I'm sure you thought of this, but ensure you're restarting your devserver (or running webpack) after each change since a running server doesn't pick up changes to the webpack config.

Comment: I dont use the devserver. I run it manually each time. But thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to this thread.  But, thought this is going to help future readers.  I am just practicing ES6 + Babel + Webpack combination and came across this video which explains on setting up develop environment for ES6/ES2015 using Babel and Webpack.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wy3Pou3Vo04

I tried exactly as mentioned in that video and worked for me with no issues.  In case if anyone is having trouble with source code/video:

**Package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Message.js**

```
export default class Message {
    show(){
        alert("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
import msg from './Message.js'
import $ from 'jquery'

$(function(){
    $("#ShowBtn").on("click", function(){
        var o = new msg();
        o.show();   
    });
});
```

*index.htm*

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="build/app.all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="ShowBtn">Show</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: ['./src/app.js'],
    output: {
        path: './build',
        filename: 'app.all.js'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[{
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query:{
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }]
    },
    watch: true //optional
};
```

The only one thing I added in the above source code for proper source maps is "devtool: 'source-map'" in webpack.config.js (of course, not mentioned in that video).

Comment: Not too late. I left that for a while but ill test it on sunday when i lm back to work. Ill update with the result. Thanks!