# ES6: No source code for webpack "cheap-module-eval-source-map" and "cheap-module-source-map" only ** WEBPACK FOOTER **

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

It used to work.
Now when I add a breakpoint:

```
saveSnippet: (title, imageUrl, role) => {

        debugger;
        ...
```

The result in chrome (53) is:

[image: breakpoint]

I tried playing with it and changing the config to **'cheap-module-source-map'** and **'eval-source-map'** and **'source-map'**. Only **'eval-source-map'** and **'source-map'** work now.

The webpack.config.js (Webpack 1.13.2):

```
  var path = require('path')
  var webpack = require('webpack')
  var CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

  module.exports = {
    debug: true,
    pathinfo:true,
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      './app/index'
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new CompressionPlugin({
        asset: "[path].gz[query]",
        algorithm: "gzip",
        test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
      })

    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: any sourcemaps used there?

Comment: I've added the webpack.config.js file. I am using "cheap-module-eval-source-map". I am thinking perhaps the fact I did an "npm update" for the project broke something but I don't know what it broke.

Comment: Ok, ''eval-source-map' seem to be working...

Comment: I believe this just started happening with Chrome 53.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39206648/85326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39958971/458193) is not exactly a fix—it's equivalent to overriding the `devtool` setting to a different (slower) mode.

The right fix was submitted in [this pull request](https://github.com/webpack/source-list-map/pull/2), and **you can now update to Webpack 1.14.0 that includes it.**

Comment: Still does not work for me with webpack 1.14.0 and `cheap-module-eval-source-map`. But `source-map` works. I'm on chromium.

Comment: Please provide a project reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

```
new webpack.EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin()
```

to your `plugins` section in webpack config.